# Notion If Formula when blank spaces

Tags: formula, notion

I was using the If formula in notion like this:
"If (Day 1 > 0, "1", "0")
Which means that when Day 1 had a date, it gives me a 1, but when it was blank it gives me a 0.
Now it looks like I cannot have 0 value on my database.
Can anyone help me please?

I tried to re-write the formula, but it doesn't matter which value I put as "false", it doesn't work if "day 1" is blank. And I need a database where eventually Day 1 will be blank, and that means I have as a value a 0.